# Join on DateTime sometimes fails between Access and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ms-access

I'm trying to join two tables in Access 2013 on date/time fields.  One table is a local Access table, the other is a linked table from SQL Server 2012.  The inner join only returns about half the values it should (both tables are originally populated from the same native Access table).

```
SELECT sample.*, r.*
FROM tblWQResultStaging_SingleParam AS r 
INNER JOIN dbo_tblWQSample AS sample 
ON (r.datetime_utc = sample.sample_datetime);
```

Sample data for tblWQResultStaging_SingleParam (this is the Access native table; data formatted per Access):

datetime_utc
07/30/91 6:50:00 PM
03/24/92 6:15:00 PM
01/29/91 9:30:00 PM
03/26/91 9:10:00 PM

Sample data from dbo_tblWQSample (this is the SQL Server linked table; formatted per Access):

sample_datetime
01/29/91 9:30:00 PM
03/26/91 9:10:00 PM
07/30/91 6:50:00 PM
03/24/92 6:15:00 PM

Outcome of query above:

sample_datetime
01/29/91 9:30:00 PM
03/26/91 9:10:00 PM

I've tried multiple SQL Server date/time field types - datetime, datetime2(7), datetime2(0), smalldatetime - and none of them work, despite refreshing the linked tables after changing the field type & deleting/reloading the data.

The best guess I've had so far is that rounding issues are causing some, but not all, dates to be loaded to SQL Server with different values from the original Access data, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: can you add some sample data and expected output? Also is sample_datetime supposed to be UTC as well?

Comment: Keep in mind that the datetime datatype has time in addition to the date. Some sample data from both sides that don't match would help make this question a lot better.

Comment: If the `JOIN` is failing, this strongly implies the values are not the same. For example `'2018-08-07T17:03:00.003' <> '2018-08-07T17:03:00.000'`. Without sampel data however, we can only guess.

Comment: My code requires matching against time and date.  Both dates are in UTC, despite only one having a _utc suffix.  As far as I can tell the dates are identical, though perhaps there's another way to look at the data to pull out any possible fractional seconds that I'm not aware of.

Comment: If you want to see if there are fractional time differences, just use `CDbl` on the column. Those will be different. Or just use my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access, dates are actually doubles, and can have more detailed time information than visible stored (e.g. milliseconds)

When comparing dates in Access with dates in SQL server, you should use the `DateDiff` function and check that the difference is 0 seconds:

```
SELECT sample.*, r.*
FROM tblWQResultStaging_SingleParam AS r 
INNER JOIN dbo_tblWQSample AS sample 
ON (DateDiff("s", r.datetime_utc, sample.sample_datetime) = 0);
```

Comment: Nice, that works!  Do you know if this will take advantage of indexes?  I'm a little worried about performance once I have a few million rows in the sample table and thousands of results to insert at once.

Comment: Nope, but cross-db indexes aren't a thing. You can't realistically use indexes if you're joining 2 tables from different RDBMSes.

Comment: That... should have been obvious to me.  Thanks!